# angular change property of scope by reference from ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an input and a button, I want when the button clicked, the value of input will be changed:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='myModel'>
<button ng-click="changeMyModel()">my button</button>
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.changeMyModel = function () {
   $scope.myModel = 'new value';
}
```

It works, but when I want to pass myModel into changeMyModel() function:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='myModel'>
<button ng-click="changeMyModel(myModel)">my button</button>

$scope.changeMyModel = function (myModel) {
   myModel = 'new value';
}
```

It does not work

I really want pass a property into a function because when I use ng-repeat, each loop, the model is different, and I can not declare n var in scope for n elements of an array when loop (I have $sope.objects):

```
    <div ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <input type="text" ng-model='object'>
            <button ng-click="changeMyModel(object )">my button</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: In JS strings are immutable, this has some side effects wherein they sort of act like primitives instead of objects, your myModel property should be an object not a string.  If it were an object with a property and you pass that object in to the function then changing the property of that model will be effective.  Also ng-init has one very special use case (for ng-repeat references to $index or other special properties) the docs state it shouldn't be used in other contexts, instead initialize things in your controller.

Comment: @shaunhusain even I pass an object, it does not work, even I pass the key of array, it does not work, too

Comment: The advice given by @shaunhusain is spot on. Ensure your model changing function takes the actual object as a parameter, but modifies the value of the object through its property. Crude example here - http://jsfiddle.net/zgybdxjb/

Comment: See http://youtu.be/ZhfUv0spHCY?t=32m for some more details on how this goes wrong and the simple rule.  The controllerAs syntax changes this rule a bit but if you're using the original style then this applies.  The answer below should be good, show a plunkr with the problem in action if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

In ng-repeat, it's OK to modify object, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
   <button ng-click="removeTask(task);">{{task.name}}</button>
  </div>
<div>
```

In controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [{id:1,'name':'test1'}, {id:2,'name':'test2'}, {id:3,'name':'test3'}];

  $scope.removeTask = function(task){
        task.name = 'abc';
  };
}
```

Or you could pass your item index in the list to your function

Answer (score 1):

You should define your variable as an object, as mentioned @shaunhusain,

I made an example [for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/ig8CJkLwEXn6qgbv8L5N?p=preview)

```
 function($scope){
       $scope.user = {};
        $scope.user.name = 'test'
       $scope.changeMyModel = function (myModel) {
          myModel.name = 'new value';
       }
    })
```

and also recommendation to [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That is really not cool that you can't treat a string property of an as an object by adding some modifier.

You want to do.

```
$scope.user = "name";

$scope.setthisscopevariable = function(scopevariable) {
    scopevariable = "newname";
}
$scope.setthisscopevariable($scope.user);
```

But that just evaluates to var scopevariable = "newname" because it passes in the string and not a reference to the scope. And there is no way to pass it in as a reference without changing $scope.user to an object with properties that you are going to set.

So you can do

```
$scope.user = "name";
$scope.setthisscopevariable = function(scopevariable) {
    /* not doing anything with scopevariable by you could */ 
    return "newname";
}
$scope.user = $scope.setthisscopevariable($scope.user);
```

Which is all good in your controller for using a function with no knowledge of the object to set a value.

Which when bound to a model it could look like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model='myModel'>
<button ng-click="changeMyModel('myModel')">my button</button>

$scope.changeMyModel(modelName) {
    $scope[modelName] = "newname";        
};
```

I didn't test that but I think it should work. It allows you to pass the $scope.myModel reference in as a string so you can then access that model in the $scope with Array syntax. This is not as clean as you want because your function still has to deal with the fact that there is an object and a child object as in the other answer, but it allows you to pass in the child object as a string instead of creating creeping children. If you want to take it a step further and have the function exist outside the controller in a library, you would still need to take into account that you need to pass an object in.

```
<input type="text" ng-model='myModel'>
<button ng-click="changeMyModel('myModel')">my button</button>

$scope.changeMyModel(modelName) {
    changeText($scope, modelName);    
};

var changeText = function(obj, property) {
    obj[property] = "newname"; 
}
```

I can't answer it in abstract coding terminology, so I thought I just try with a laymen's example. :)